# How do I set database default Encoding?

Tags: sql-server, database, encoding

How do I set the the default encoding of my local file SQL-Server database?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Removed the UTF-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming by encoding you mean collation, you can change the default for new databases like:

```
alter database model collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The change the collation of an existing database:

```
alter database YourDbName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The list of available collations is returned by a system function:

```
select * from fn_helpcollations()
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support UTF-8.

Use nvarchar (UTF-16) if you don't mind using double space or varbinary if you don't need sort/indexing/comparison.

It may be supported in next release of SQL Server according to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362867&wa=wsignin1.0) post

Answer (score -3):

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */
```

Something like that

Comment: That's a MySQL comment statement, not SQL Server