# How to set encoding of database in Microsoft Server Managment Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to set encoding of database in Microsoft Server Managment Studio?

I need to set utf8 to my database and I can't find option in settings of database.

Comment: Do you mean to change the collation of the SQL Server instance or of a specific database? I'm not sure what you really want to do; where do you encounter a text encoding when dealing with the DB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set database default Encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680073/how-do-i-set-database-default-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set UTF8 encoding to SQL Server database.

You can use char/varchar data types to save characters- one character = one byte- but that also means you can save only limited characters (see collations).

You can use nchar/nvarchar data types to save characters- one character = two bytes (its UCS-2. for sorting, searching.. see collations).

Finally in varbinary column you can store UTF8 or whatever you need :).

Answer (score 1):

It is taken from here [How do I set database default Encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680073/how-do-i-set-database-default-encoding)

Assuming by encoding you mean collation, you can change the default for new databases like:

```
alter database model collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The change the collation of an existing database:

```
alter database YourDbName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The list of available collations is returned by a system function:

```
select * from fn_helpcollations()
```